# Which sentences are ok to use?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases, nouns, adjective-phrases, conversation

Which of the following makes sense to use :

1- I feel fatigue.
2- I feel fatigued.
3- I perceive fatigue in your voice.
4- I sense fatigue in your voice.

Comment: All these expressions are rather formal. In everyday conversation you would say "I feel tired" and "You sound tired."

Comment: Without context it is impossible to know what makes sense.  If I'm slowly sinking in quicksand and crying out for rescue, your saying, *I perceive fatigue in your voice,* makes no sense whatsoever, even though my continued cries for help may very well suggest fatigue.

Answer (score 0):

Sentences 2, 3, and 4 are fine. Sentence 1 is not.

When "feel" is used to describe our perception of self, it is an intransitive verb and so takes an adjective as a complement.

> I feel angry
>
> i feel happy

The grammar is exactly analogous to

> I am angry
>
> I am happy

"Fatigue" when used as a noun means a **state** of tiredness or weakness. It is therefore an abstract noun. Individuals are not abstractions. Therefore saying

> I am fatigue

is nonsense (unless you are writing allegory and have personified some abstractions).

"Fatigue" is also used as a verb, meaning "to make someone tired." The perfect (passive) participle of a transtive verb can be used as an adjective.

> I am fatigued

makes sense: it means that something unspecified has tired or weakened you. Thus,

> I feel fatigued

is idiomatic, but

> I feel fatigue

is not.

In sentences 3 and 4, the speaker uses transitive verbs, and such verbs require nouns or pronouns as an object rather than an adjective.

Words like "fatigue" that can be used as both a noun and a verb are a bit tricky.

Comment: Although I think you could make a case of "fatigue" as a noun... in the same way you could say, "I feel anger" or "I feel heat"... Would be a strange way of saying it but I still think grammatically acceptable.

Comment: "Feel fatigue" seems [common in medical contexts](https://www.healthline.com/health/fatigue-and-loss-of-appetite) where it denotes a specific condition or set of symptoms. Outside that, it's not usual, probably because "fatigue" isn't usual, but "I feel hunger", "I feel rage", etc, are more common.